# Hide EmptyDataTemplate but leave header visible

Tags: asp.net

I have an EmptyDataTemplate on my ASP.NET webform which allows users to add a record to the database. Depending on the permissions of the user, this EmptyDataTemplate needs to be visible and hidden if no data is found (I have this working!) 
For example, my user has Read Access only. When they search a specific criteria, no results are displayed they cannot see the EmptyDataTemplate. However, if they search a criteria, and there is data, data is displayed WITHOUT the headers.

Can someone please help explain why this is happening and if there's a way around it?

The headers are HeaderText on TemplateFields.

I'm hoping it's a general trick. 
Thank you in advance for your help!
Please note, it's the HeaderText in the TemplateFields I want to display- not the  in the emptyDataTemplate as they'll head up the columns of data that match the search criteria.

edit: code added as requested
For hiding the EmptyDataTemplate:

```
     protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = null;
        control = GridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0];

        if (userManagement.getMIFReadWriteAccess() == "Read")
        {
            control.Visible = false;
            Export_All.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (userManagement.getMIFReadWriteAccess() == "Write")
        {
            control.Visible = true;
            Export_All.Visible = true;
        }
}
```

in markup for the header text (i've only shown one column but the markup is the same for all of them)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Index" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>

                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

EmptyDataTemplate:

```
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                           <div id="emptyData" runat="server">
                             <tr>
                              <th></th>
                                <th>Serial Number</th>
                                <th>Comments</th>
                                <th>Review Date</th>
                                <th>Approved By</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btInsert" Text="In" OnClick="Add" CommandName="EmptyDataTemplate" Class="Button" OnClientClick="return confirm('You are about to confirm this action. Please confirm this action by clicking OK. If you do not wish to do this, please select Cancel.');" />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btInsertOut" Text="Out" OnClick="AddOut" CommandName="EmptyDataTemplate" Class="Button" OnClientClick="return confirm('You are about to confirm this action. Please confirm this action by clicking OK. If you do not wish to do this, please select Cancel.');" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_Serial_Number" CssClass="text"></asp:TextBox>
                               </td>
                                <td>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="tb_comments" Width="100%" MaxLength="50" runat="server" placeholder="max 50 characters"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="tb_reviewDate" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:dd/mm/yyyy}"  Text='<%#Eval("review_by") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="tb_approved_by" runat="server">                    
                    </asp:DropDownList> </td>
                            </tr>
</div>

                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Hi, i've added it now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I found that programatically adding a header row in C# did the trick. Probably not the best way of doing it, but it worked.

Code is as follows:

```
#region show the emptyDataTemplate depending on user rights

    Control control = null;
    control = GridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0];

    if (userManagement.getMIFReadWriteAccess() == "Read")
    {
        control.Visible = false;
        GridViewRow HeaderRow = new GridViewRow(1, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert); 

        TableCell HeaderCell2 = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell2.Text = "Country";
        HeaderCell2.ColumnSpan = 1;
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell2);

        //Repeat the above for every column of data you have!

        GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderRow);
```